# Generating a state diagram from legacy C code

Tags: c, uml, state, graphviz, dot

I'm looking into visualizing a large amount of C code, preferably having its state machine reverse engineered and graphed out for me diagrammatically.

I've looked into Graphviz and Dot, and it appears that I could probably stitch something together from the API to do the job.  But honestly I kind of expected that it would have been a common enough task that someone may have already come up with a tool to do the task.

Does anyone have experience with this?  Any solutions you can recommend or tools that exist that I've overlooked?

Thank you.

Comment: You expect a tool to just inspect the code, figure out which states exist, and when transitions happen, all automatically? That sounds like a tall order, to me.

Comment: C isn't exactly a language encouraging a state machine.  A significant proportion of code will thus have a significantly large number of states that are not conducive to a diagram.

Comment: What do you mean by "its state machine"? Control flow graph? Really the state machine that the code is compiled to? Or some state machine that is defined by your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Enterprise Architect but that's really not a good idea and in any case you'll need to do a lot of manual changes to the result. It's more or less like relying on an automatic translator to speak for you in the language you don't know. It's especially problematic for procedural type of code, like you probably have if it's in C.

Comment: To follow on... All responses here nudged me into more clearly seeing that generic visualisation of a state machine is not exactly possible.  I looked into the commercially available tools mentioned, they all seem to stop short of promising state machine diagram generation.  The most feasible solution appears to be to use pre-processing or scripting on the code to output Dot code and generate bespoke diagrams using some variety of Graphviz.  A consistent enough syntax in the state machine code should allow for this.  Here's hoping it's consistent...